# jenkinsfile doesn't recognize @Grab

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to use @Grab to include a yaml parsing library inside my Jenkinsfile. I add this line in my Jenkinsfile:

```
@Grab('org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.17')
```

https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml

However, the Jenkins run can't recognize this and return an error.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use `@Grab` in pipelines at the moment. I doubt it will be added as a feature because Jenkins CPS needs source code to be able to perform CPS transformations, and `@Grab` uses binary dependencies. You can only use `@Grab` from trusted shared libraries. From [the documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#using-third-party-libraries):

> It is possible to use third-party Java libraries, typically found in Maven Central, from **trusted** library code using the `@Grab` annotation. Refer to the [Grape documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html#_quick_start) for details, but simply put:

Comment: so a workaround would be to put those code in a shared library and import it in Jenkinsfile?

Comment: That is one way. Another would be to use an existing plugin, for example [`readYaml` and `writeYaml` from the _Pipeline Utility Steps_ plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readyaml-read-yaml-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text).

Comment: I had the same issue (exactly the same version of yaml), as it is mentioned in the documentation of Jenkins you'll need to go to the link (Maven Central) and search for the dependency, turned out, version 1.17 doesn't exist there but you can use version 1.23 and it works. Although I read that doc earlier I didn't understand what exactly it means until I read @mkobit comment, Thanks