# Use @grab in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

As described in those documentations
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/
http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html#_quick_start

I want to use @Grab inside my Jenkinsfile but I have an error

```
@Grab('com.blabla:MyArtifact:0.1.0')

import com.blabla.MyClass
```

And I have this error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: No suitable ClassLoader found for grab
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor25608.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247)
>       at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.chooseClassLoader(GrapeIvy.groovy:182)
>       at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy$chooseClassLoader.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
>       at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.grab(GrapeIvy.groovy:249)
>       at groovy.grape.Grape.grab(Grape.java:167)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
>       at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:46)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.callStatic(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:102)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
>       at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$2.call(Checker.java:188)
>       at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedStaticCall(Checker.java:190)
>       at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$checkedStaticCall$6.callStatic(Unknown Source)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:222)
>       at WorkflowScript.(WorkflowScript)
>   Caused: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.createScript(InvokerHelper.java:434)
>       at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:131)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:125)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:560)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:521)
>       at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:330)
>       at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
>       at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
>   Finished: FAILURE

I checked my artifactory, and my artifact is actually inside. If i try to grab a wrong version, I have another error.

Comment: `@Grab` is not how the documentation describes how to retrieve shared libraries. Look here: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#retrieval-method

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm using this method to retrieve my personal pipeline library. But in this case, I can't use SCM to load the artifact.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jenkinsfile doesn't recognize @Grab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51328182/jenkinsfile-doesnt-recognize-grab)

Comment: The topic was closed in 2013. As you can see in the documentation, now Jenkins supports the grab mechanism.

Comment: The documentation says you can use the `@Grab` from within trusted library code, and says nothing about within a Jenkinsfile.